# QT widget signals - comprehensive list?

Tags: qt4, pyqt, widget

Looking for a comprehensive listing of the various SIGNALS emitted by the built in QT4 widgets. Have looked around - can't seem to find one. (Using PyQT 4.x and Python 3.2)

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code lists all signals for all QObject subclasses in QtGui:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import inspect
for name in dir(QtGui):
    obj = getattr(QtGui, name)
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, QtCore.QObject):
        for name2 in dir(obj):
            obj2 = getattr(obj, name2)
            if isinstance(obj2, QtCore.pyqtSignal):
                print name, name2
```

Comment: thanks! I guess you truncated the last line when you copied it - for 3.2 I used: **`if isinstance(obj2, QtCore.pyqtSignal): s=name+": "+name2 print (s)`**

Comment: works fine - formatted it HTML, now I have my own index. Although just now I did see that the PyQT docs list signals for each widget, after the methods, this is easier.

Answer (score 4):

I would think that the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/classes.html) has all available signals.

Comment: Thus far I Haven't found the comprehensive list index I'm looking for up there - thus my question. But just now I did find the QSignalSpy and QSignalMapper classes - hopefully I can get them working in PyQT.

Comment: I guess you would have to write a crawler, if you want all signals on one page.